# Given the Bode diagram here, what choice of gain will give approximately at 50 degree phase margin?

Tags: matlab, model-view-controller, controls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXWwX.png)
This is a Bode diagram problem, can anyone provide me with a solution? Maybe it's an easy question, but bear with me, I'm a beginner in this field.

First, we need to find the position of -130 degrees。in the phase diagram. The value of the amplitude plot is then read at that frequency. This amplitude value will tell us how much gain we need to increase or decrease in order to reach 0dB at that frequency.